# Pack files with preserving file creation time in Windows?

Tags: windows, archiving

Is there any packing/archiving software that can preserve not only file modification timestamps, but also **file creation** timestamps?

Software must be **freeware**, and with UTF-8 support in filenames.
Compression is not necessary.

7zip doesn't preserve file creation timestamps, because it's developer has disabled this feature: https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/5c86e830/

Answer (score 1):

First don't blame the Authors of 7-zip as the inclusion of the Last Modified Time, *without the file creation time* is a feature of the zip format as specified by PKWARE as you can see in [the specification](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).

Since version 6.2.1 of the specification there has been defined an "Extra Field" structure and format and the "-NTFS Extra Field" variant of this currently has a single tag, Tag1 which is defined as:

```
     Tag        Size       Description
     -----      ----       -----------
     0x0001     2 bytes    Tag for attribute #1 
     Size1      2 bytes    Size of attribute #1, in bytes
     Mtime      8 bytes    File last modification time
     Atime      8 bytes    File last access time
     Ctime      8 bytes    File creation time
```

Note that the specification specifically says that if extra fields are present that the platform does not understand then the entire file that they are defined for should be skipped which will make any zip files created with a program that adds them specific to such tools - as a result the general advice is **not** to implement them.

I believe that [WinRAR](http://www.win-rar.com/features.html?&L=0) may provide support for this in several of it's archive file formats but it is not Freeware *although there is a trial version available.*

The tar file format does include the ctime as well as mtime and can optionally compress files and the PAX format supports Unicode file names. A full, free, command line, implementation of tar for Windows is available as [gtar](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm) and there is a free, open source, archive manager [PeaZip](http://www.peazip.org/peazip-portable.html) that does store the creation date in such formats but unfortunately the creation date is only displayed in the individual file properties not as a column in the main GUI windows.

Comment: "First don't blame the Authors of 7-zip as the inclusion of the Last Modified Time, without the file creation time is a feature of the zip format" — This shouldn't really be an issue for 7-Zip's native file format, 7z, which doesn't even use the same compression algorithm as ZIP by default.

Comment: @Kodiologist pkzip was a child of MS-DOS & Early MS-Windows and MS-DOS - MS-DOS used FAT-16 which did not record creation data before DOS-7 - unlike early *NIX implementations.